# Описать рекурсивную ф-у для ряда n-го члена ряда 10, 5, 5/2, 5/4...5/256

Tags: c++, рекурсия

> Как прийти к выходу из рекурсии, допустим мы вводим 4 число, это 5/4, мы должны дойти до 10 и потом разделить число n-ое кол-во раз на два. Как прийти к этой 10? Спасибо

```
    int func(int n)
{
    if (n == 10)
        return 10;
    return func() / 2;
}

int main()
{
    int n, d;

    cin >> n;

    d = func(n);

    if (d <= 10)
        cout << d << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что можно так:

```
double func(double value, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return value;
    return func(value/2, n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << func(10, n) << endl;
}
```

Comment: получается, value/2, n-1 выполняется за один вызов return ?

Comment: Не понял, в чем состоит ваш вопрос... Этот "вызов return" приведет к очередному рекурсивному вызову...